# Get result rows in sql developer window

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I run following procedure in sql developer window to search all oracle tables for specific string and at the end in Statement Output window it says "anonymous block completed" and now can't understand where is result rows, how to get it?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have option in SQL Developer

and also you have to execute your procedure as below

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Testing output');
end;
/
```

Click ->View->Dbms Output and then click + symbol on Dbms output window. now you can run the procedure and can see output.